# Sending custom HTTP error information to Flash, JavaScript, etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, http, rest, error-handling

I'm developing a REST API at the moment, and one of the core features of this is that is uses a variety of HTTP status codes to return status/error information, some of which may be extended information (e.g. if an item is not found, some other similar items) which will be in the response body.

This is fine until you get to 'crippled' clients like Flash and JavaScript which can't access the response body or headers unless the HTTP status code is 200 OK (even a 201 Created success code can cause Flash to fail thinking it's an error).

So my question is, is there a standard way for allowing this type of client to request that all status codes are HTTP 200, and to indicate the *real* status code in another way?

One solution I was thinking of is, in the pattern of the HTTP `Accept-*` family of headers, using an `X-Accept-Status` extension header to specify which status codes can be handled, e.g. Flash would send...

```
X-Accept-Status: 200
```

...and then any status code not in this list would be mapped to one that is, and the error returned in the response body, possibly with another extension header indicating the real status code, e.g.

```
X-HTTP-Status-Code: 404 Not Found
```

This all seems a bit horrible, and working against the protocol, but if you have clients that cannot use the protocol property then that's unavoidable. I'm just looking for something a bit like `X-HTTP-Method-Override` (which is a 'standard' way of working around the protocol for clients that cannot send `PUT`/`DELETE` requests) but for clients that cannot understand status codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, actually the problem with `HTTP` and `REST` is, that `REST` is a really good idea, and `HTTP` describes a really good implementation of it ... but really, many clients and servers only implement part of `HTTP` ...

i don't think `HTTP` is a must ... still, `REST` is a good idea and `REST`fulness of a system is a powerful property ... so why not use `HTTP` as a stupid transport layer for a `REST`ful system?

this is what you are doing, although in my opinion, you are holding on a bit too much to `HTTP` and all it's theoretically built-in features ... do you really need to transport the information in a status code?

don't depend so much on your transport protocol/layer ... have a clear idea in mind, how your service should work ... seperate the protocol semantics from its implementation ... on both client and server ... abstract your `REST`fulness and status codes too (make them more then just integers ... make it enums, or objects ... exceptions, why not?)...

and then plug-in protocols/transport layers at will ...

- make a standard `HTTP` implementation
- make a hacky one, using the solution you described (which to me seems perfectly valid ... if people are using technologies unable to use the standards, why should you bother too much finding the most standard-conform solution)
- make whatever you have the time to do, and your server is able to do, binary, `JSON`, `XML` ... whatever seems adequate ...

*two technical notes, though:*

1. flash player does it's `HTTP` traffic over the browser ... and it simply does not get the status codes from the browser ... well it depends on the browser in fact ... the specs say, it does not work for: "Netscape, Mozilla, Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer for the Macintosh." ... so IE for windows should be working? Chrome? I don't know ... but i think, it doesn't matter, since obviously, you cannot rely on it ... oh, and to state the most obvious: JavaScript also does its `HTTP` over the browser, of course ... so same problem here ...
2. for both this implies, that if you would succeed in finding something like `X-HTTP-Method-Override` for response, that is built in the protocol, a good browser would understand that, and would remap things accordingly, **before** deciding which information to give to JavaScript or 3rd-party plugins ... so you'd end up with nothing again ... i guess ...

you should simply choose your response method based on the client ... and maybe the client should send some extra info, if it is unable to use the `HTTP` standard ... otherwise throw at it, what follows the standard ... i'd first make an implementation using standard `HTTP`, yet hiding the `HTTP` itself away, and once everything works, write one using

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong for thinking that one shouldn't let a crippled out-of-the-box potential client to the API dictate the features of the API implementation?  I guess practical considerations win the day, but in general I guess my vote is in favor of building API implementations "properly" and requiring custom client-side programming as needed.

Comment: The problem is when there's simply no way for the client side to consume the application built 'properly'. Just imagine the conversation with your manager... You: "No, we can't let [insert big company here] use out API even if they will pay us [insert lots of money here] because they can't call it in the perfect way.". Boss: "Change it so they can call it. Now."

Comment: -1. The potential client (Adobe Flash) isn't in-and-of-itself crippled, but crippled/constrained by the legacy browser plugin NSAPI.  We're talking about just about any plugin technology having this issue, in many common browsers.  Favor practicality over purity.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for that response, but...

When I implemented a flash client API with an early version of OpenRasta, I had X-ResponseLine that contained the response code and text, on each outgoing request.

As headers are by default only generic headers, they have no involvement in caching, so no reason to have an Accept / Vary on this.